# Send cookie to localhost with AWS lambda and python

Tags: python, http

I am trying to send a cookie to my react app. I am on the dev server on my local machine at local host 3000 but for some reason my cookie never gets set in the browser. How do I fix this?

```
 return {
        "statusCode" : 200,
            'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : True,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET',
            'set-cookie': 'cookiemonster-test=yumyumyum; SameSite=None'
        },
        'body': response_body,  
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "with lambda"? Lambda functions run on external servers and don't have access to local client-storage for cookies. They also don't run react code

Comment: AWS lambda is sending the response back to a React Fetch

Comment: Okay, so have you tried using [`document.cookie = ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie)? Or [install `react-cookie` module and `import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';` and call `setCookie` function from it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie)? Simple returning a JSON response isn't going to set any cookies. And if you are trying to do an HTTP header, capitalization matters, and it is [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#the_set-cookie_and_cookie_headers)